# How do I Search Instagram Posts by Location

Tags: python, instaloader

I'm trying to search instagram posts with instaloader using the #hashtag

```
posts = instaloader.Hashtag.from_name(L.context, "python").get_posts()
```

but how can I search the posts by location like Dallas...?

```
posts = instaloader.Location.from_name(L.context, "Dallas").get_posts()
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](https://instaloader.github.io/module/instaloader.html?highlight=location#instaloader.Instaloader.download_location)

Comment: Nope actually I'm trying to see the post from this search

https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/212900916/dallas-texas/